# Using CCZE with multiple log files

Tags: linux, bash, log-files, gnu-screen

I am looking for a solution to watch live several logfiles on ccze.

Currently I send a tail of each file in a pipe, this pipe is used by ccze for display all logfiles needed.

The problem is that some log files are much more used than others, ccze don't keep a "fixed position" on the screen, so the most used logs just hide the least used.

I would therefore like to know how to get the set of log files via ccze always visible (I thought of screen but I would like to know if other options exist).

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I configure all of my servers to send logs at a level of **notice** and above to a remote log server, running syslog-ng.

I then configure syslog-ng on the remote server to pipe the console output through **ccze** as follows:

```
destination du_pts0 { program("ccze -r > /dev/pts/0"); };
```

This colorizes the output on the logserver console.

In order to see this on a remote terminal I use:

```
destination du_fifo { pipe("/var/log/logtail"); };
```

...and put the following in my ~/.bashrc file:

```
ccze < /var/log/logtail
```

Comment: "I would therefore like to know how to get the set of log files via ccze always visible (I thought of screen but I would like to know if other options exist)"

Your solution does not allow me to see all the configuration files at the same time, the scrolling problem still exists, unfortunately: (

Comment: I think I have missed the point of your question.  Sorry.  However, you could raise the level of logging from "notice" to "warning", and reduce the amount of logs you see.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by 'always visible' - you want to have certain lines stay on screen while the rest is scrolled away? That's hard to do with ccze, perhaps you need a different log viewing tool. Have you tried `multitail`? It let's you see several log files at once in different windows, and also provides colorized output.

Comment: Its exactly what i want. I'll watch multitail, thank you :)